# Opening a Django InMemoryUploadedFile leads to an I/O operation error?

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am attempting to upload a file to a bucket using Django.  The file goes in from the view, is cleaned, and is then uploaded to s3 using a utility function in the model.

heres the upload function:

```
def upload_file(file_obj, object_name=None):
    """Upload a file to an S3 bucket

    :param file_obj: File to upload
    :param object_name: S3 object name. If not specified then file_obj is used
    :return: True if file was uploaded, else False
    """

    bucket = settings.BUCKET

    # If S3 object_name was not specified, use file_obj
    if object_name is None:
        object_name = file_obj

    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    try:
        s3.upload_fileobj(file_obj.open(), bucket, object_name)

    except ClientError as e:
        logging.error(e)
        return False
    return True
```

the error returned is:

```
  File "/opt/profiles/profiles/core/utils.py", line 217, in upload_file
s3.upload_fileobj(file_obj.open(), bucket, object_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/files/uploadedfile.py", line 90, in open
    self.file.seek(0)
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
```

Now whats weird to me is that the error comes from file_obj.open(), whats the point of an open method that cant open a closed file?  I don't want to pass the request.file straight from the view as I have in a property setter, and would like it to fire off whenever the property is changed in the model but I simply cannot figure out what the correct process should be.

Answer (score 0):

Well, part of the error at least comes from setting two file fields.  As soon as you set one, the file object is done, essentially.